# How can I serve banana flambée for the next day?

Tags: bananas, flambe

How can I serve banana flambée the following day without it going bad. This is for a French Project about MArtinique.

Comment: Are you talking about Bananas Foster? Because that's not a French recipe, it's from Brennan's Restaurant in New Orleans (USA). And since the main idea of that recipe is the presentation (i.e. the flambé), I'm having a little trouble figuring out why you'd want to make it in advance... or do you want to prepare everything in advance *except* for that part?

Comment: @Aaronut I get a lot of hits on bananas flambee, independent of the well known bananas foster.  It looks like there is a regional variant to Martenique, with lime juice an cinnamon.  http://buenvivir.net/buen-vivir-recipes/martinique-rum-flambc3a9-bananas  I have to admit, I was initially thinking Foster as well.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  you cannot reasonably make bananas flambee ahead.

While it would be conceivably possible to prepare your caramel and cook the bananas through the day before, you would then need to refrigerate them over night.

Reheating them would be tricky, and might even take more time than preparing them in the first place--and you would not want to serve them without reheating, as the dish would be gloppy and dissonant between the hot parts from the flambee, and the still cold parts.

This is a dish best served a la minute, that is, prepared at the moment of service.   There is little prep work that can be done the day before that will save you significant time.